# Include post_status check within $wpdb query

Tags: wp-query, database, wpdb, sql

I've got a function that returns a count from the database for publish posts that match the product ID to the post meta ID (both are the product type). I've realized this query returns unpublished posts as well.

I've tried for a couple of hours to figure out how I can include a defensive check to only include posts that have the `post_status` of `publish`

```
public function get_number_of_stars_for( $star_value ) {
        global $wpdb;

        return $wpdb->get_var(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT COUNT(wpm2.`meta_value`)
                    FROM $wpdb->postmeta as wpm2,
                    (
                        SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE `meta_value` = %d AND `meta_key` = 'review_product'
                    ) as wpm1
                    WHERE wpm1.`post_id` = wpm2.`post_id` AND wpm2.`meta_key` = 'review_rating' AND wpm2.`meta_value` = %d
                ",
                $this->post->ID,             
                $star_value
            )
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

To get the post status, you'll need to `JOIN` the posts table based on the `post_id` you grabbed from `wpm1` or `wpm2` and extend your `WHERE` clause to use that joined data.

### Recommendation

On the other hand, instead of going directly to the database to get your content, you could use `WP_Query` to process this content. See below for a quick example. I highly recommend testing this code before adding it to your site.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => 1, // This is a heavy-handed approach to limit result to one
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'review_product',
            'value'   => $this->post->ID,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$all_ids = $query->posts[0]; // Most likely want to change this to a foreach so you can find the right value

$args2 = array(
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'review_rating',
            'value'   => $all_ids,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);
$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
return $query2->post_count;
```